# Default value of command

Tags: macros

I have the following command:

```
\newcommand{\plusbinomial}[3][2]{(#2 + #3)^{#1}}
```

This command takes 3 parameters and the default value of the first parameter is 2.

If I don't want to use the default value, then I would call it like this:

```
\[ \plusbinomial[4]{y}{y} \]
```

My question is, how do I define default value for all the parameters and how should I call it then?

Comment: I'm not sure in what `\plusbinomial[4]{a}{b}` is easier than `(a+b)^{4}`.

Comment: it is usually a bad interface design to have more than one optional parameter as if you make all three optional it is very hard to have a natural usage, you can not use the third argument unless you provide the first two so they are no longer really optional.

Comment: This is an example given in the ShareLaTeX @egreg

Comment: @Robur_131 you should put braces around `#1` in that code.

Comment: Edited. @Skillmon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
I agree with David Carlisle that it is generally bad practice to have multiple optional arguments with default values. If you want to give the last argument a value, you also have to provide the prior arguments. For these kind of macros, it might be more clear to use a `key=<value>` structure for the arguments. The following example uses `pgf` for that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfkeys{
    /plus binomial/.cd,
    a/.initial={5},
    b/.initial={8},
    c/.initial={2},
}

\newcommand{\plusbinomial}[1][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/plus binomial/.cd,#1}%
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/plus binomial/a} + \pgfkeysvalueof{/plus binomial/b})^{\pgfkeysvalueof{/plus binomial/c}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \( \plusbinomial \)

    \( \plusbinomial[c=9] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[c=9,b=1] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[c=9,b=1,a=3] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[c=9,a=3] \)
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following, which is more intuitive:

[image]

---

Without a package this can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\plusbinomial{%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
        \plusbinomial@i%
    }{%
        \plusbinomial@i[2]% Default is 2
    }%
}
\def\plusbinomial@i[#1]{%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
        \plusbinomial@ii{#1}%
    }{%
        \plusbinomial@ii{#1}[5]% Default is 5
    }%
}
\def\plusbinomial@ii#1[#2]{%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
        \plusbinomial@iii{#1}{#2}%
    }{%
        \plusbinomial@iii{#1}{#2}[8]% Default is 8
    }%
}
\def\plusbinomial@iii#1#2[#3]{(#2 + #3)^#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \( \plusbinomial \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9][1] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9][1][3] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9][][3] \)
\end{document}
```

But if you're willing to include the [`xparse`](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) package, this becomes a *lot* simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\plusbinomial}{O{2} O{5} O{8}}{(#2 + #3)^{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \( \plusbinomial \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9][1] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9][1][3] \)

    \( \plusbinomial[9][][3] \)
\end{document}
```

With exactly the same result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could test whether any of the arguments is a star/asterisk (`*`) and substitute a default value whenever this the case. This is how that would work: (with default values `2`, `1` and `\delta` for `#1`, `#2` and `#3`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\defaultifstar[2]{\ifx*#1 #2\else #1\fi}
%% \defaultifstar{#1}{#2} --> #2 if #1 is a *, and --> #1 otherwise
\newcommand*\plusbinomial[3][2]{(\defaultifstar{#2}{1}+\defaultifstar{#3}{\delta})^{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\plusbinomial{x}{y}$,
$\plusbinomial*{y}$,
$\plusbinomial{x}*$,
$\plusbinomial[3]{x}{y}$,
$\plusbinomial[3]*{y}$,
$\plusbinomial[3]{x}*$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The above method actually only tests if the first token of `#1` is a `*`, so it fails spectacularly when you pass an actual argument that happens to start with a `*`. So don't use it if this is likely to happen.
*(To test whether the argument is equal to `*` you could replace `\ifx*#1` by `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{*}{#1}=0` for pdfLaTeX, `\ifnum\strcmp{*}{#1}=0` for XeLaTeX and `\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{*}{#1}` for LuaLaTeX (last one requires the [`pdftexcmds`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds) package).)*

You could also test if an argument is empty and use a default value then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\defaultifempty[2]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax #2\else #1\fi}
%% \defaultifempty{#1}{#2} --> #2 if #1 is empty, and --> #1 otherwise
\newcommand*\plusbinomial[3][2]{(\defaultifempty{#2}{1}+\defaultifempty{#3}{\delta})^{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\plusbinomial{x}{y}$,
$\plusbinomial{}{y}$,
$\plusbinomial{x}{}$,
$\plusbinomial[3]{x}{y}$,
$\plusbinomial[3]{}{y}$,
$\plusbinomial[3]{x}{}$

\end{document}
```

⟨ The output is the same ⟩